# Placeholder text is returned when using value property of input text box in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, webshim

I am using webshim to provide the html5 placeholder functionality in my textboxes in IE8.

This works fine when I submit the form - the field is blank if the user has not entered anything.

But when I tried to jazz things up by making an ajax request hooked to an onclick event the following line of code returns the placeholder text instead of an empty string.

```
document.getElementById('idOfTextBox').value
```

How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: can you use jquery for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V31, that was super quick! You are correct, jquery gets it right.

```
$('#idOfTextBox').val()
```

gives the correct result

Comment: have a look at my answer it will work for all forms in your page and do add a jquery tag to the question as well

Comment: One note here. Why this works is explained here: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Guide-dom-abstractions Webshim does not extend the DOM itself, but all jQuery standard methods to seamlessly work with HTML5 properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could set this as alternative

```
if ( document.getElementById('idOfTextBox').value=='placeholder' ) {
    document.getElementById('idOfTextBox').value='';
}
```

basically, if the textbox value = the placeholder, it will set the value to '' (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

Since the placeholder fix puts the value in the textbox and change the style to appear as a placeholder, you need to fix it before submitting it. Please find the code in jquery below:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
});
```

Do not that in the textboxes where you want to remove the placeholder have the class 'hasPlaceHolder' so that it can find them

As per OP the jquery selector worked

```
$('#idOfTextBox').val()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is necessary. Form submission worked fine with webshim placeholders. Selecting the value from the textbox using jquery also works. getElementById().value didn't work.

Comment: oh ok was giving you a general answer which I did in my case as it was an issue for me as well if it had worked using the jquery selectors then nothing like it :)